# Can I use CancellationTokenSource.Cancel and CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(timeSpan) for the same task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I didn't see this in the docs anywhere -

If I want to use `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(600000)` as a failsafe in case my `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` call never gets called.

Will the `CancelAfter()` interfere with the `Cancel()` call in any way?

Comment: As the CancelAfter [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=net-6.0) say, _"When the millisecondsDelay expires, this CancellationTokenSource is canceled, **if it has not been canceled already**._

Comment: The documentation could indeed be more explicit on this, but `.Cancel()` is a one-time deal. Meaning that any `.Cancel()` after the first one does nothing, and `.CancelAfter()` is just a way to schedule the `.Cancel()` for later. (Per stuart, it so happens that `.CancelAfter()` itself actually *is* explicit on this, but `.Cancel()` itself is not, nor the general class docs.)

Comment: @stuartd - I just missed that one sentence! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, no interference. When a `CancellationTokenSource` is canceled, it's an atomic operation. Either the `Cancel` will occur first and will dispose immediately the active `CancelAfter`-related timer, or the timer will be triggered first and the subsequent `Cancel` will be a no-op.

If you want you can study the source code of the [`Cancel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel) method [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2e998c2712e5e09af2ad7258441a884170b25982/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L221).